# Excel VBA userform existing date validation

Tags: excel, vba, validation, date, userform

I am currently working on a textbox (textbox1) in which the date must be entered. However, until now it is also possible to enter a non-existent date, for example 40-40-2019. Is there a way to validate textbox1 with only existing dates? I currently use the European date entry, so dd-mm-yyyy. And the code below to change the date to a standard format:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
 Me.TextBox1 = Format(Me.TextBox1, "DD-MM-YYYY")
End Sub
```

I expect the output to be only existing date functions

Answer (score 0):

Use `Isdate()` to test for date:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Isdate(Me.TextBox1.Text) then
        Me.TextBox1.Text = Format(Me.TextBox1.Text, "DD-MM-YYYY")
    Else
        '...
    End if
End Sub
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isdate.php

Comment: Hi, This won't help to validate if the date is existing, am I right?

Comment: @WouterGroeneweg, no, but the assumption is you will have to manually fix already filled in dates anyway. If this is a huge data set you could do the `Isdate` in a loop of the column(s) and highlight the dates that need to be fixed.

Comment: Yes this will tell you if the the date "exists" i.e. is valid. In the Else statement you decide how to respond to an invalid date. You could remove the existing text or give a message to the user.

Comment: @D_Bester Thank you very much for your help!